# Spring Annotate in the class level with @EnableScheduling

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I have a service class with functionality to make an async call. The code is provided below,

```
@Service
public class EllaService {

    @Async
    public void invokeEllaAsync( final IrisBo irisBo ) throws EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException {

        if( !isTrafficIgnored( irisBo ) ) {
            try {
                callEllaService( irisBo );
            }
            catch( EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException ex ) {
                throw new EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException( ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause() );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to annotate in the class level with `@EnableScheduling` to work it properly?

Comment: `@EnableScheduling` is connected to `@Scheduled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate your main with `@EnableAsync`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html